# Filter out items in list view using jslink

Tags: list-view, jslink

I have a list view, containing GUIDs, where I want to filter out some items depending on the result of a REST call made in the onPreRender function in my JSLink. The REST call fetches GUIDs from another list, and if they match the ones in my current list I want to render and display the items. But if they don't, I don't want the item to show at all, it should be removed. Is this possible?

I tried manipulating the ContextInfo and removing the items I didn't want, but that resulted in errors, to no surprise.

So what I want is to remove entire rows from the list view, not just values in a specific field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Option 1. How to remove row in List View

The following example demonstrates how to delete rows via client side rendering

```
(function () {


   function listPreRender(renderCtx) {

         var excludeRows = [0,2,3];  //row idexes to be excluded

         var rows = renderCtx.ListData.Row; //get current rows
         for(var i = excludeRows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var rowIdx = excludeRows[i];  //get row index to exclude 
            rows.splice(rowIdx, 1);  //delete List View Row
            renderCtx.ListData.LastRow = rows.length;  //update ListData.LastRow property
         }        
   }


    function registerListRenderer()
    {
       var context = {};
       context.Templates = {};
       context.OnPreRender = listPreRender;

       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

### Option 2. How to hide row in List View

```
(function () {

   var excludeRows = [0,2,3];

    function renderListItemTemplate(renderCtx) {
        if(excludeRows.indexOf(renderCtx.CurrentItemIdx) > -1)
        {
           return ''; //do not render row
        }
        return RenderItemTemplate(renderCtx); 
    }


    function registerListRenderer()
    {
       var context = {};
       context.Templates = {};
       context.Templates.Item = renderListItemTemplate;

       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

### Results

Original List View

[image]

After 
[image]

Comment: I tried option number two and i works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: @Vladim: I tried both solutions with some modifications (I have some conditions on how to remove items). It works good so far - but I noticed the paging count is not updated correctly. i.e. I have 7 items left and a page count of 30 - but the paging is displayed with 1-6 and 31-7? What update needs to be done?

Answer (score -3):

You need to add an IF statement in your rendering function.  Something like:

```
function CustomItem(ctx) {
 var ret = '';
 if ($.inArray(ctx.CurrentItem.GUID, ArrayOfGUIDs) != -1) {
  ret = '<div>' + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + '</div>';
 }
 return ret;
}
```

In this example I have used a jQuery function to see if the GUID exists but if you do not have jQuery then use an alternative comparison.