# Return CurrentItem from context.Templates.Item JSLink

Tags: 2013, javascript, jslink

Any ideas on how to return from the Custom Item method when using JSLink (as if it was never called)? I want to do a check in this method and hide the row if the condition fails. I know I can do a PostRender, but then I will have to loop through each row again.

```
overrideContext.Templates.Item = customItem;

function customItem(context) {
   if(conditionIsNotMet)
      return context.ListData.Row;
   else
      //Hide Row somehow

   //Tried return context.CurrentItem, return null, return "", return context.ListData
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this post: [Filter out items in list view using jslink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91317/filter-out-items-in-list-view-using-jslink)

Looks like you could do:

```
overrideContext.Templates.Item = customItem;

function customItem(context) {
   if(conditionIsNotMet) {
      return RenderItemTemplate(context);
   }
   else {
      return '';  //Hide Row somehow
   }     
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robin. That post was helpful but what did the trick was RenderItemTemplate(context); I have made the edit. Thanks again