# Sharepoint List View with 50 individual web parts dificult to maintain

Tags: web-part, list-view

I have a public Sharepoint View to show a list of items.
I edited that view to include several web parts (around 50).
Each web part has targeted audiences and is visible only by one sharepoint group, that includes the users related to a corporate area.
So naturally, each web part has a diferent "query" (OOTB) to select the items of the particular area.

The idea behind this solution is to have only 1 view (more simple) and to ensure that the users only see the items they should see (security). Those are the requirements.

The solution works but is very troublesome to mantain:
If i have 2 or 3 fields to change in the view (add/subtract), for instance, i have no choice but to change each individual web part (50 times) included in the view to modify the fields selected (in the query).
Considering Sharepoint Perfomance, this is a boring and lenghty task...

Therefore, i would like to know if anyone can propose a better solution for this problem that requires less time to maintain. I would like to  address the list of fields (similar to all web parts) just once, instead of 50 times. The fields are always the same, although the filter to obtain the items change. I should not change the list of fields 50 times.

Thank You
Nuno

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using just one List View webpart and change the rendering of the items in the webpart using JS link [Filter out items in list view using jslink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91317/filter-out-items-in-list-view-using-jslink).

As per your requirement the only difference you have in all the 50 webparts is the filter, which you can easily change using JS link. So, in each item rendering in JS link check if that item should be seen to the current user and then render it.